# Get the resource id for the drawable reference used in styled attribute

Tags: android, custom-controls, android-resources, declare-styleable

Having this custom view `MyView` I define some custom attributes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="MyView">
        <attr name="normalColor" format="color"/>
        <attr name="backgroundBase" format="integer"/>
    </declare-styleable>   
</resources>
```

And assign them as follows in the layout XML:

```
    <com.example.test.MyView
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        . . .
        app:backgroundBase="@drawable/logo1"
        app:normalColor="@color/blue"/>
```

At first I thought I can retrieve the custom attribute `backgroundBase` using:

```
TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyView, defStyle, 0);
int base = a.getInteger(R.styleable.MyView_backgroundBase, R.drawable.blank);
```

Which works only when the attribute is not assigned and the default `R.drawable.blank` is returned.
When `app:backgroundBase` is assigned an exception is thrown *"Cannot convert to integer type=0xn"* because, even though the custom attribute format declares it as integer, it really references a `Drawable` and should be retrieved as follows:

```
Drawable base = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.MyView_backgroundBase);
if( base == null ) base = BitMapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.blank);
```

And this works.
Now my question:
**I really don't want to get the `Drawable` from the TypedArray, I want the integer id corresponding to `app:backgroundBase` (in the example above it would be  `R.drawable.logo1`). How can I get it?**

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It turns out that the answer was right there:

```
TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyView, defStyle, 0);
int base = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.MyView_backgroundBase, R.drawable.blank);
```

Comment: some clarification that would have helped me: the `R.drawable.blank` is the default resource in case the requested one does not exist

Comment: Thanks for this, i didn't know i could refer to the resource ID. getResources().getIdentifier()is one of the great mysteries of Google.. (their documentation absolutely sucks)